# How to create a matrix with a loop performing pycode

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, foreach, pythontex

Okay, so there are a bunch of questions that are SO close to what I am trying to sort out, but I can't find a combination of approaches to make this work (I am so sorry if this has been answered elsewhere---I'm not sure I really knew what to search for).

My issue is, once I have added everything to the `\mymatrixcontent`, the final calculation shows up in every slot.

I have to imagine the issue has to do with where/how I am expanding things, but I can't figure it out.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pythontex}


\begin{pycode}
def foobar(number):
  return 2 * number
\end{pycode}

% commands so I can use the variable in the pycode
\newcommand {\inttopy}[2]{ \expandafter \inttopytwo \expandafter {#2}{#1}}
\newcommand {\inttopytwo }[2]{\pyc{#2=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \n in {1,...,30}{
  \inttopy{changingNumber}{\n} % so I can use the year later in calculations
  \xdef\myVariable{\py{foobar(changingNumber)}}
  \xappto\mymatrixcontent{|[draw, circle,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=2pt]|\n \expandonce{\&} \expandonce{\myVariable}}
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}
  
\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
column sep=2ex,  label={Matrix}
] (m){
\mymatrixcontent 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: If you check the `pytxcode` file you will see that `changingNumber` will be set to 1, 2, …, 30 before thirty `foobar(changingNumber)` will appear. It may not execute the Python statements in the same order they appear in the document. Using `\py{foobar(\n)}` seems much more naturally, in my opinion.

Comment: Wow...okay, well I did something else very wrong. Dunno how I got the impression that wouldn't work.

Comment: So, the underlying problem is that `\py` is made robust (meaning `\myVariable` will just by `\py{…}`) and (even if it were) doesn't simply expand to the Python returnment. So it basically is another expansion issue but besides using `\n` instead of `changingNumber` I don't see a way to solve this with PythonTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\py` is made robust, meaning it does not expand in an `\edef`/`\xdef`.

The second column will always just be `\py{foobar(changingNumber)}` but when this will actually be typeset (after the loop and inside the matrix) `changingNumber` has been last set to 30. (And these Python assignments won't be grouped by the `\foreach` loop as other things would be in similar cases which usually throw an error.)

In this simple case

```
\edef\myVariable{\py{foobar(\n)}}
```

will be enough since `\n` will be expanded to its value.

I've simplified the loop a bit furthermore. We can just use the low-level `\pgfmatrix…` macros directly without having to worry about ampersand replacements.

### Code

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pythontex
% arara: pdflatex
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{pycode}
def foobar(number):
  return 2 * number
\end{pycode}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \n in {1,...,30}{
  \xappto\mymatrixcontent{\n   \noexpand\pgfmatrixnextcell
               \py{foobar(\n)} \noexpand\pgfmatrixendrow}
}
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  column sep=2ex,
  column 1/.append style={
    nodes={
      draw, circle, minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=2pt}},
  label={Matrix}
] (m){\mymatrixcontent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]